# Buttons in DataGridColumn Header Template - unexplained spacing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a data grid which has a `DataGridTemplateColumn` that looks something like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SomeStrings, Source={StaticResource proxy}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Width="30" Margin="0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Left">
                                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="270" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Width="30">
                            <Button>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </Button>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The idea is to have a dynamic set of "columns" in a datagrid but having a single column that is, itself, a `StackPanel` and by having the same thing in the `CellTemplate` I can get everything to line up nicely. The idea came for here: http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/populating-a-datagrid-with-dynamic-columns-in-a-silverlight-application-using-mvvm/

It works well enough for what I'm doing. However, I want to wrap the `TextBlock` in the `HeaderTemplate` in a `Button`. So something like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SomeStrings, Source={StaticResource proxy}}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Width="30" Margin="0">
                        <Button>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Left">
                                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="270" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Button>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

The problem is that this introduces some extra spacing and I can't for the life of me figure out where it's coming from:

[image]

Notice that without the buttons, it lines up great, but with the buttons it's shifted a few pixels to the right. Where is it picking up this extra spacing? And how can I make it not do that? I could just get a negative left margin on my `StackPanel`, but that feels like a horrible hack.

As you can see, the same problem doesn't happen in the `CellTemplate` for whatever reason.

**Complete Example**

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <FrameworkElement x:Key="proxy" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed"
             Content="{StaticResource proxy}"/>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SomeStrings, Source={StaticResource proxy}}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border Width="30" Margin="0" Background="Pink">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="270" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                                                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </Border>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border Width="30">
                                            <Button>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                            </Button>
                                        </Border>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SomeStrings, Source={StaticResource proxy}}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border Width="30" Margin="0">
                                            <Button BorderThickness="0">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Left">
                                                    <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                                        <RotateTransform Angle="270" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                                                    </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                                </TextBlock>
                                            </Button>
                                        </Border>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border Width="30">
                                            <Button>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                            </Button>
                                        </Border>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string[] SomeStrings { get; set; } = new[] { "Foo", "Bar" };

    public List<string[]> SomeData { get; set; } = new List<string[]>() { new[] { "a", "b" }, new[] { "c", "d" } };
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Note: I added background color to the example without the buttons and I'm now not convinced that they are lined up accept by total accident. I think because the text labels are aligned to the top (which once rotated becomes the left-hand side), they appear to line up, whereas when you add the button the label gets shifted to the center and don't line up anymore

Comment: Isn't it because buttons have different margin/padding than labels ?

Comment: @Aybe: The rendered size of the labels and the buttons are the same. The button's margins are set to `0`, so that doesn't seem to be the cause.

Comment: Have you tried that little black box to debug your XAML tree ? Alternatively you have https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ or http://xamlspy.com/

Comment: @Aybe, yeah, I've been messing around with that and it looks like it's the `ContentPresenter` directly underneath `DataGridHeaderBorder` that is shifted, but I have no idea why. It's `Margin` is set to `0,0,0,0` and the padding on the `DataGridHeaderBorder` is also `0,0,0,0`

Comment: I think you should post a complete mini example people can copy/paste to further try.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand your issue, to me bottom data grid is the one that is centered, cell values being left-aligned. Top data grid headers to me sound unaligned ... Looking at that link, it seems to be a really awkward-student way to alleviate deficiencies of Silverlight. Why don't you simply populate an appropriate template for the datagrid columns for the source it is currently displaying ? That would make things simpler and separate concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Default a `Button.HorizontalContentAligment` is `Center`, where as a `Textblocks.HorizontalAlignment` is `Left`. So when you are wrapping your `TextBlock` in a `Button` it gets centered but your Textblock gets layed out on the left..

All you need to do is set the top `TextBoxes` Horizontal Alignment to Center, and you will get identical look:

```
<Border Width="30" Margin="0" Background="Pink">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="270" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
    </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

[image]

If you want them to be completely lined up, get rid of the `Padding` in `DataGridColumnHeader` (N.B. setting it to 0 causes it to be overriden possibly by some trigger? Haven't got time to investigate at the moment. But if you set it to the following:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,1" />
</Style>
```

You will get the spacing you desire:

[image]

Comment: Setting the padding in the `DataGridColumnHeader` worked. Thanks.